# Don't scroll to anchor when linking to bootstrap tab from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap tabs - which works fine on the page, but not when you link from another page, because it jumps down the page to the content. Is there any way to turn off this behaviour or do I have to customize Bootstrap javascript myself?

Thanks.

(Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863870)).

Comment: could you add a short fiddle or some relevant code please?

Comment: Apparently it doesn't work properly on JSFiddle. I tried... http://jsfiddle.net/czk60ae1/2/embedded/result/#settings

Comment: Maybe this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659072/jquery-disable-anchor-jump-when-loading-a-page

Comment: I had tried that - it scrolls down then jumps back up. I think he's using jQuery tabs rather than bootstrap?